# Can not override Icon from checkbox => error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fontSize')

Tags: material-ui

```
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';
import FavoriteBorder from '@mui/icons-material/FavoriteBorder';
import Favorite from '@mui/icons-material/Favorite';
```

**Works**:

```
<Checkbox icon={<FavoriteBorder />} checkedIcon={<Favorite />} />
```

**Works not:**

```
 MuiCheckbox: {
          defaultProps: {
             icon: <FavoriteBorder /> ,
            checkedIcon: <Favorite /> ,
          }
        },
```

**Error**
'Favorite' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Favorite'?ts(2749)

**When I change it to this:**

```
 MuiCheckbox: {
          defaultProps: {
            icon: FavoriteBorder,
            checkedIcon: Favorite,
          }
        },
```

**I get this RUNTIME exception:**

boundary error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fontSize')

**Question**:
What do I wrong?

And why do I run into a bug from 2020 :D

with latest MUI... 5.x

https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/21289

Comment: You need to share more code -- the error is not reproducible with the code that you provided. https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-sun-c8dmq2?file=/Demo.tsx